# Slim PHP Framework Help

Tags: php, rest, frameworks, slim

I just added the Slim framework to my website in order to create a rest API. But I currently have a problem. I wrote this code as a test to check to see if a get request would work, but whenever I try calling the url, http://mysite.com/api/rest/hello/max, I get a website not found error. Please can you tell me what is going wrong?

```
Slim::init();

Slim::get('/hello/:name', 'hello');

function hello($name) {
    echo "Hello, $name!";
}

Slim::run();
```

Comment: Have you setup your rewrite rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have propably forgotten to put the `.htaccess` file provided with `Slim` in the same directory as your `index.php`.